# how to set Linearlayout Center inside relative layout in android

Tags: android

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"
            android:fillViewport="true"

            android:paddingLeft="80dp"
            android:paddingRight="80dp"
            android:paddingTop="40dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/appLogogImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/circular_textview_drawable"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="72dp"
                    android:layout_height="72dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_share_illustration" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/appTextview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/appLogogImageView"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_4x"
                android:text="Sharing is Caring"
                android:textColor="@color/colorDusk"
                android:textSize="20.1sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"


                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/appTextview"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                android:text="Share ContSync with your friends to get them onboard"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlueyGrey"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />


        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

// toolbar .xml


      <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:elevation="@dimen/app_bar_default_elevation"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.Event.Toolbar.Title"
                    tools:title="@string/label_select_your_country" />
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

https://pasteboard.co/
```

This is my Xml and current Screen you can see the imageview which is inside Linearlayout is not set center . i  have puted gravity center in Linarlayout but its not   set center  i dont know what mistake i am doing even  on tool bar also i tried to set shadow below but its not coming can any one please suggest me what i am doing wrong.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

this is my expected screen   in my current Screen and using current xml i am not able to set Imageview which is coming inside linear layout is not center and also toolbar below shadow is not coming please suggest me how to keep its center and how to put shadow below on tool bar as expected screen.

Comment: you want the layout to be exactly at the center right ?. I think below answer is doing that. doesn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this make your `LinearLayout` `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` like below code

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/appLogogImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_textview_drawable"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_share_illustration" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#689F38"
        android:gravity="center">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/layout_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_white_bg" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="SHARE"
        android:textColor="#ffff" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="80dp"
        android:paddingRight="80dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/appLogogImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/appTextview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/appLogogImageView"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
                android:text="Sharing is Caring"
                android:textSize="20.1sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"


                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/appTextview"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:letterSpacing="-0.03"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                android:text="Share ContSync with your friends to get them onboard"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: when i try this then linearlayout goes below

Comment: @MakleeLee share your whole layout code it working fine in my device

Comment: @MakleeLee remove **`android:layout_below="@+id/header"`** from your Relative layout parent of Linear layout

Comment: in my Screen its coming center but its goes down its not as expected Screeen i have to keep that Image top padding 40 dp but its coming center

Comment: @MakleeLee remove **`android:paddingTop="40dp"`** from your relative layout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160562/discussion-between-maklee-lee-and-nilu).

Answer (score 0):

In `LinearLayout` add this line`android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to make it center in parent of `RelativeLayout`

Comment: i did same thing but its linearlayout goes down

Comment: @MakleeLee Your code https://codepaste.net/qap7uq working fine for me. It looks center in my layout.

Comment: But look my Expected Screen Image is started from top with 40 dp